# Losing static IP and and getting DHCP IP

Tags: debian, networking

I have a Debian 7.1 machine that is our internal intrusion detection system running snort.  It has started flaking on me and will pull a DHCP address even though I have it set to static.  This happens every few hours.

Here is my `/etc/network/interfaces`

```
    # This file describes the network interfaces available on your system
    # and how to activate them. For more information, see interfaces(5).

    # The loopback network interface
    auto lo eth0 eth1
    iface lo inet loopback

    # The primary network interface
    allow-hotplug eth0
    iface eth0 inet static
            address 10.10.10.107
            netmask 255.255.255.0
            gateway 10.10.10.1

    iface eth1 inet manual
            up ifconfig $IFACE 0.0.0.0 up
            up ifconfig $IFACE promisc
            down ifconfig down
```

Comment: Can you check the Debian version you mention? If you really have a Debian 3.2 (and not a recent Debian with a 3.2 Linux kernel), I recommend you strongly to upgrade it. There is no longer any support for such old versions. As attacks change over time, it is important to have recent snort rules.

Comment: @jofel There never even *was* a Debian 3.2 [according to Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Debian#Timeline). After Sarge/3.1 came Etch/4.0.

Comment: @MichaelKjörling Yes, there was no official 3.2 release. But according to [this thread](http://translate.google.de/translate?ei=Gxj5UYvuM834sgad1IDYCw&ie=UTF8&sl=de&tl=en&u=http://debianforum.de/forum/viewtopic.php%3Ff%3D8%26t%3D80764%23wrap) Debian 3.2 was (at least some time) the version of Debian testing before Debian 4 was released.

Comment: Oops, I guess that is kernel version.

Answer (score 5):

There is probably `network-manager` or `wicd` running. Disable/Uninstall it. You can temporarily shutdown `network-manager` with `service network-manager stop`.

There could be also some `dhclient` programs in the background. Run

```
ps ax | grep  [d]hclient
```

or

```
pgrep dhclient
```

so check if there are DHCP clients running. You can kill them via `killall dhclient`.

Theoretically, there are other DHCP clients with different names, but it is unlikely that they are installed.

Comment: No network-manager or wicd installed.  I killed dhclient so I will check on it at the end of the day and see if it has flaked on me again.  Thanks.

Comment: The Network Manage can be used for other interfaces. Killing or removing it may be not a proper solution.

Answer (score 0):

I know I am late to the party here, but I just wanted to add on to this one. I was getting a DHCP address on my network interfaces even though they were set to static.  I was even getting this in Ubuntu 20.04 with `ifupdown` installed and using `/etc/network/interfaces` with manual IPs set.

I added the following to `/etc/dhcpcd.conf` to stop all my NICs from getting the DHCP address above any configured interface: (I am using 2 NICs both set at eth0 and eth1)

```
denyinterfaces eth0 eth1
```

*This will prevent your interfaces from getting DHCP IPs even when they are set back in the `/etc/network/interfaces` file, so make sure to comment out or remove this line before re-enabling.*

After restarting my network `sudo /etc/init.d/networking restart` no more DHCP addresses showing up.